# Styling for plolty heatmap

Tags: python, plotly

I would like to only show one column of this heatmap "Total Wins", so it would be the first veritcal column. I want the graph to still be a plotly object that has a legend and is interactive.

'''

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
corr = new_best_teams.corr()
corr = round(corr,3)
mask = np.triu(np.ones_like(corr, dtype=bool))
new_best_teams_mask = corr.mask(mask)

fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(z=new_best_teams_mask.to_numpy(), 
                                  x=new_best_teams_mask.columns.tolist(),
                                  y=new_best_teams_mask.columns.tolist(),
                                  colorscale=px.colors.diverging.RdBu,
                                  hoverinfo="none", 
                                  showscale=True, ygap=1, xgap=1
                                 )

fig.update_xaxes(side="bottom")

fig.update_layout(
    title_text='Heatmap', 
    title_x=0.5, 
    width=1000, 
    height=1000,
    xaxis_showgrid=False,
    yaxis_showgrid=False,
    xaxis_zeroline=False,
    yaxis_zeroline=False,
    yaxis_autorange='reversed',
    template='plotly_white'
)


for i in range(len(fig.layout.annotations)):
    if fig.layout.annotations[i].text == 'nan':
        fig.layout.annotations[i].text = ""

fig.show()
```

'''

Here is an image of the output: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDVmq.png)

Here is an image of what I want (I want it to still be an interactive plotly graph with the legend included): [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I34To.png)

Comment: Isn't it possible to do this by limiting the data to the data you want to output, rather than adjusting it on the graph side?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you do not need a mask nor upper triangle. Try to just slice the first column and plot it:

```
corr_total_wins = corr.iloc[:, :1]
fig = fig.ff.create_annotated_heatmap(corr_total_wins)
```

An alternative to ff is https://plotly.com/python/imshow/